# Upload buddy press profile picture from custom page template

Tags: buddypress

I want to make a page template from where the user can upload the custom profile picture for their buddypress profile.

Answer (score 0):

By default a Buddypress user can update their profile picture at `/members/$username/profile/change-avatar/` - if your theme isn't exposing that option something might be broken in your profile template.

Edit: this functionality is exposed in `/members/single/profile/change-avatar.php`, can you just include that in your custom template? If not, examining the functions used on there should get you started.

Comment: I am making a custom page template not using the default one. So need to know how can I code the functionality

Comment: Updated my answer.